# Copy images from one S3 bucket to another with specified path prefixes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip, aws-sdk

I have an S3 bucket setup already, it contains images of a photo gallery, uploaded from my Rails app using PaperClip. Images are accessible via some arbitrary URLs like: http://s3.amazonaws.com/oldbucket/images/files/000/001/920/original/40a6885fc09c8ed4e1e3745d7f7fb770.jpg?1415766995.

Kindly advice me the best option considering following requirements:

1. I have to copy those images to another S3 bucket in another AWS
   account
2. I want to make the new image URLs according to specific
   patterns, like: .../newbucket/{userid}/{galleryid}/{image-size}.jpg
3. I want to create multiple versions of each image, according to size
   (original, thumbnail and icon)

Any options using Rails gem or software that would do above would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to add `carrierwave` gem for saving image from remote url. You can also do with paperclip.

First create a seed file without adding carrierwave uploader to your app. I am considering User as model and avatar as image.

```
User.all.each{|u| puts user.avatar.url}`
```

Now remove `paperclip` and add `carrierwave` This will give you list of all images. Now add it to seed file for model you want to add this images.

```
class Modelx
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

So your seed file should have entries like.

```
Modelx.create([{:avatar_remote_url => image_url1}, {:avatar_remote_url => image_url2},.....])
```

You can set specific path and also create multiple dimension images using carrierwave.

REfrence url for carrierwave [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave).

Comment: Thanks Dipak, few things i need to clarify. 1) What do you exactly mean by creating a seed file? 2) Because previously images are stored on S3 using PaperClip so I can access them through PaperClip back as binded to data in database. So what if I could not remove PaperClip and install carrierwave as well ? 3) Is Modelx and User same thing ? 4) Please explain the last line of code "Modelx.create([{:avatar_remote_url ...}])"